# Screensharing option is not working in Skype 8 with Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: xorg, 17.10, skype, wayland

I have installed Skype 8 in Ubuntu 17.10, in that the screen sharing option is not working. The option itself is not available in the "**+** option" during the call.

It was working fine in Ubuntu 17.04